# how to disable screenshot for a pdf viewer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

We were given a task of disabling the screenshot option for a PDF viewer in mobile view . I have tried using code but wasn't able to give a blank page either. Please can someone help me in this..

```
    @media print {
                 html, body
                {
                 display: none;
                }
                }
```